# Node version reports different version than installed

Tags: node.js, unix, archlinux, nvm

In order to use aws cdk I'm required to update node, **but** apparently I'm already set. I must have installed nodejs **without** pacman but can't rememember how. Any ideas where to start in order to get it right?

`$ sudo pacman -S nodejs`

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) nodejs-20.6.0-1

Total Download Size:   13.85 MiB
Total Installed Size:  58.63 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.34 MiB
```

`$ node --version`

```
v14.17.5
```

`$ which node`

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/node
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the version with `nvm`

```
$ nvm use 20
Now using node v20.6.0-1 (npm vXXXX)
$ node -v
v20.6.0-1
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the -a argument to for which?

```
# man which:
#   -a      List all instances of executables found 
#           (instead of just the first one of each).

$ which -a node

# or install mlocate, run updatedb, then use 

$ locate node
```